# Fedora 23 SmartGit installation

Tags: git, ssh, smartgit, fedora-23, rootkit

In lieu of finding any workaround for keypairing my mostly-standard Fedora 23 installation (default SELinux if that helps) to BitBucket's SSH authentication wall, I've been working to get Smartgit installed but the current revision can't seem to scope JRE no matter how many copies I export to $PATH.  My hope is that if I get Smartgit figured out I can let their Oauth implementation do the heavy lifting.  I've been wrangling this so long I even offered to build Syntevo some RPMs gratís.

So has anybody defined a solid workflow for getting Smartgit in F23?  Backtracking on distro updates isn't something I'm ready or willing to do just yet, though I'm open to VM or code ball related solutions.

One thing I strongly suspect my original requirement is related to is the Ebury Windigo SSH exploit; something I suppose forms a routing backend for some new botnet. I found my F23 install afflicted via chkrootkit and what I know right now is that disabling remote SSH login privileges via GKSU permissions fixed the network bottleneck it caused. If I can I'll post a resolution for the SSH worm itself. If anyone has a clean gpg-checksum'd copy of lib-keyutils I should be able to post an answer that lets everyone stay comfortably in their terminals rather than these squirly clients.

The only 2 hosts I've contacted over SSH are Bitbucket & Github: if any *Nix or OSX users can do so, I emphatically suggest avoiding those hosts until patches are publicized or at least until such time as SSH can work around these vulnerabilities.  Or until it can be verified that they didn't allow such an injection at least. **We don't know where this came from yet.** This worm's been versioned up & recursively spreading through a whole lot of upstream repositories, that much I can say for certain.

I should add that I'm still waiting to hear back from Syntevo support about this. There seems to be a certain degree of general nastiness leveled at the Fedora community from the Canonical side of things.

Comment: Have you checked readme-linux.txt?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly the problem is? Doesn't SmartGit start? Or, if it does, is there some log.txt output you can post?

Comment: It supplies the same error output as the installation script.  There doesn't seem to be any CLI invocation.  Smartgit being closed source there's no other output I want to chase down while I'm still waiting to hear back from Syntevo unless someone here thinks dmesg or the like could be of help.

Comment: There's only the broken .sh installer; for some reason it preferentially scopes OpenJDK i386 JRE; I've tried modifying it to include /usr/java/ JREs as well as copying OpenJDK into ~/smartgit/bin/ with the stock script.  The  only vector I haven't gotten around to trying is modifying the installer script to scope the relative installroot path & include JRE strictly within its' own folder permissions.  That & manually unpacking all the relevant JRE deps in situ.  Didn't work in /opt/smartgit/ either.

Smartgit's Alacarte shortcut works in gnome and I see the process created but nothing more.